# XCode: iOS Enterprise in house app signing errors

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing, enterprise

I'm using XCode 5, iOS 7.0.6, iPhone 5S

My company is trying to deploy a test inhouse app with the enterprise program (not the actual app, we just want to try figuring out the deployment). I have been invited as a member to the enterprise program, and I requested a development certificate through XCode.

In the Build Settings, I have:

```
Code Signing Identity -> iPhone Developer: ...
Provisioning Profile -> iOS Team Provisioning Profile: * (Wildcard)
```

It builds and archives fine, but when I tried installing the app, I received an error "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements." After googling, I followed the suggestions to toggle a setting in the Capabilities tab. I clean, build, archive again, and this time, I'm getting the error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." Am I setting the code signing/provisioning profile incorrectly? Those are the only ones I have access to.

I am unclear of Developer Certificate vs Distribution Certificate; do I need a Distribution Certificate to install the app on devices?

Note: I'm trying to install the app through Apple Configurator, since that's how we want to deploy the app to employee devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, not valid as he is using iOS 7.0.6 and the linked answer states that solution is for 7.1

Comment: @Fogmeister As Matthew Hallatt said, I'm on 7.0.6 instead of 7.1, and, I'm trying to install the app via Apple Configurator instead of AdHoc. I'm getting the errors I mentioned from Configurator.

Comment: Ah, sorry, close vote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Distribution Certificate if you want to install it Ad hoc.

Comment: I'm installing through Apple Configurator instead of AdHoc, do I still need a Distribution Certificate? If so, I don't see a way to do this through XCode or member center; do I need an admin to create one for me?

Comment: In this case I'm not sure. Did you try to use a provisioning profile which is not a wildcard profile?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm only a member of the team, therefore I can't create provisioning profiles. The wildcard is the only one available to me. I'll ask an admin to create one for the app. Thanks!